# Labour Law - Minimum notice period to prevent breach of contract scenario

Tags: contract-law, employment, breach-of-contract

James is hired by company X in South Africa.

The first and second year's he is given a **fixed term contract** (Period 1 year each).

The third year he is offered **permanent employment** and remains at Company X for 18 months when suddenly he decides to resign.

James checks his permanent employment contract's resignation paragraph:

*The following notice periods will apply for the respective working periods:        Where the working period is: 
(i)  Less than six (6) months:   one (1) weeks’ notice. 
(ii)  Six (6) months or longer – but less than one (1) year:  one (1) calendar months’ notice. 
(iii)  Longer than three (3) years:  three (3) months’ notice.*

Which notice period does James need to give to not be in breach of contract?

Comment: Unanswerable without knowing which jurisdiction applies to this contract

Comment: @Dale M. The Jurisdiction is South Africa.

Comment: There is no notice period for employment lasting between one year and three years. That's either a critical lack of information in your question or a major loophole that would let you walk out the same day, given a consistent and reasonable arbiter of fact and contract law.

Comment: @Nij, I totally missed that until you mentioned it. That resignation clause is what is actually stated in the contract.Am I correct that you are also inferring that the 2 fix term contract periods are ignored when calculating my employment duration, so in other words, am I seen as only being 18 months at the firm?

Comment: That would be a very interesting case to decide on. Presumably you  didn't write the contract,  so the fact that they chose not to have a notice period for employees of that time means they  don't want a notice period, and you simply don't have one...

Comment: ... but I wouldn't rely on that without talking to a lawyer first. I would personally not infer that - continuous employment is continuous employment regardless of the terms, and employment court would tell the employer that in my home jurisdiction. Which is not RSA, so again, speak to a lawyer.